# How to adjust texts aligned at the both ends and how to put the text in the middle of a fixed length underline

Tags: align, underline

I tried to align text like this:

[image]

with the "aa"s aligned at the both ends, and "bb"s in the middle of a fixed lendth underline. I tried to use `\justifying` and `hfill`, but it did not output the disired texts, how can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{minipage}{3cm}
        \justifying
        Aa aa:\\
        Aa aa aa:\\
        aa aa aa aa:\\
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{7cm}
        \underline{\hfill bb \hfill}\\
        \underline{\hfill bb bb bb \hfill}\\
        \underline{\hfill bb bb bb \hfill}\\
    \end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look at \mbox: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly a comment to [User23456234](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/278534/user23456234): The `\makebox` is a perfect solution IMHO, but my personal golden rule is to maintain the code as simple as possible. Without a context to see the convenience of set or calculate lenghts, I would just do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\centering\parskip1ex
\makebox[3cm][s]{Aa aa:}
\underline{\makebox[7cm]{bb}}\par 
\makebox[3cm][s]{Aa aa aa:} 
\underline{\makebox[7cm]{bb bb}}\par
\makebox[3cm][s]{aa aa aa aa:}
\underline{\makebox[7cm]{bb bb bb bb}}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]